# how to find probability of uniformity of data

Tags: variance, mean

I was working on image processing where I have some list of pixel value eg:-[5,2,5,2,4,2,4,2,2,2] so I found mean as 3 and variance as 1.77778

My question is how to find the probability of data been distributed eg
if data is [1,1,1,1,1] then the probability should be 1 , if data is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] then the probability should be 0. how to calculate the probability and what is probability of data distributed for [5,2,5,2,4,2,4,2,2,2].

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're actually asking for here.

Comment: i need to find how uniform the data is distributed but is should be scored in between 0 to 1.

Comment: The problem seems to be one of communication. I'm guessing you mean "how nearly constant are the pixel values (against pixel order say)", whereas "uniformity" to a statistician will mean something like "how nearly constant is the probability distribution of different values", a fundamentally different issue. If I have correctly discerned what you're after, I'd suggest altering your question to avoid the word 'uniform' and to include some additional description (or even some plots) of some typical situations and what ultimate questions you're trying to answer ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... (since your question at present doesn't seem to be well formulated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a useful resource to get started: It covers chi-square tests for uniformity.

http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/uhan/sa421/lessons/08.pdf

This can be easily computed in any statistical software including Excel.